# Finding index of target using recursive binary search in C

Tags: c, recursion, binary-search

I'm only allowed to use the given parameters. I can't wrap my head around the thought of finding the index of the target. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int RecBinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {

    if (len <= 0)
        return 0; 

    int mid = len/2;

    if (target == arr[mid]){
        return 1;
    }
    if (target < arr[mid]){
        int i=0;
        return RecBinarySearch(arr, mid, target);
    }

    else {
        return RecBinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target);
    }
}

int main(void){
    int arr[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int len=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int target = 5;
    RecBinarySearch(arr,len,target);
}
```

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: So this code will return the target value, but I need to find which position it is in. In this case since the target is 5, it should return 4.

Comment: .I can't wrap my head around how I could find the index **because I can't increment anything with the given parameters** - Explain the bold part.

Comment: What problem do you have with the code you show? Does it work? Perhaps you should return `mid` when the target is found? And return e.g. `-1` when not found?

Comment: @coderredoc I just realized that it wouldnt work even if I incremented something by putting in a parameter. Let me delete that part.
Someprogrammerdude, The code works but I'm trying to find the index of the target, but I don't know how to start.

Comment: https://www.ideone.com/0OekRC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Ideone link](https://www.ideone.com/0OekRC)

```
#include <stdio.h>
int RecBinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {
    if(len <= 0) return -1;
    int mid = len / 2;
    if(arr[mid] == target) return mid;
    if(arr[mid] < target) {
        int rightIndex = RecBinarySearch(arr+mid+1, len-mid-1, target);
        return rightIndex == -1 ? -1 : mid+rightIndex+1;
    } else {
        int leftIndex = RecBinarySearch(arr, mid, target);
        return leftIndex == -1 ? -1 : leftIndex;
    }
}

int main(void){
    int arr[6]={1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int len=sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int target = 5;
    printf("%d", RecBinarySearch(arr,len,target));
}
```

Comment: Can you explain to me what return rightIndex == -1 ? -1 : mid+rightIndex+1; does?

Comment: -1 is to denote that the target is not present in the array. rightIndex comes from recursion. If it comes -1, so it means the target is not found and we have to return -1 too.

Answer (score 1):

1st : you don't really need recursivity in this goal. You might more efficiently replace it with a loop, using left and right marker (recursivity is quite expensive for various reasons).

2nd : Instead of returning 0 or 1, which you don't use, you should return mid or -1 if not found, and since you shifted your array in the recursive call (passing array+mid+1), you should add the shift value to the return value, and then you get the position in the return value in main.

Answer (score 1):

Given that, **I'm only allowed to use the given parameters**, you can use following. See it working [here](https://ideone.com/E8wLwb):

```
int BinarySearch(int arr[], int len, int target) {
    int startI = 0, endI = len-1;

    while(startI<=endI)
    {
        int mid= (startI+endI)/2;
        if(arr[mid] == target)
            return mid;
        if(arr[mid] < target)
        {
            startI = mid +1;        
        }
        else
        {
            endI = mid -1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: This isn't recursive though.

Comment: @Groo Yaa... But this is not mentioned in the OP post that it _must be a recursive solution_. That's why I mentioned that _Given that, I'm only allowed to use the given parameters_.

Comment: @cse the question isn't the best but the title says "using recursive binary search in C".